# Why `apropos url` output 'url (7)' but I can't use the command url

Tags: command-line

I want a URL encoder. So I `apropos`ed it in the terminal and received following

```
$ apropos url   
uri (7)              - uniform resource identifier (URI), including a URL or URN
URI::URL (3pm)       - Uniform Resource Locators
url (7)              - uniform resource identifier (URI), including a URL or URN
urn (7)              - uniform resource identifier (URI), including a URL or URN
```

But when I type `url` it outputs:

```
$ url                                                                                
No command 'url' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rl' from package 'randomize-lines' (universe)
 Command 'ul' from package 'bsdmainutils' (main)
 Command 'erl' from package 'erlang-base' (main)
 Command 'erl' from package 'erlang-base-hipe' (universe)
 Command 'uil' from package 'libmotif-dev' (multiverse)
 Command 'uil' from package 'lesstif-bin' (universe)
 Command 'curl' from package 'curl' (main)
url: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `apropos url` will return something like `url(1)` then you can to use `url` as a command-line. Until then, `url(7)` will refer at a macro  package or a convention (miscellaneous).

> The number corresponds to what section of the manual that page is
>   from; 1 is user commands, while 8 is sysadmin stuff. The man page for
>   man itself (man man) explains it and lists the standard ones:
>
> ```
> MANUAL SECTIONS
> The standard sections of the manual include:
>
> 1      User Commands
> 2      System Calls
> 3      C Library Functions
> 4      Devices and Special Files
> 5      File Formats and Conventions
> 6      Games et. Al.
> 7      Miscellanea
> 8      System Administration tools and Deamons
>
> Distributions customize the manual section to their specifics,
> which often include additional sections.
> ```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean.

Comment: How can I use User Commands (1) ?

Comment: @totti Maybe you want to use `curl` or `lynx` (`lynx` is not installed by default). What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks. But I like know how to use it

Comment: @totti What to use? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @totti [`man url`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/url.7.html) doesn't give you enough documentation?

Comment: Have more look.

Comment: May I have more look at the answer and links